# SAML client id how is it stored

Tags: saml

I'm knew to SAML and i'm trying to understand how a clients details are stored for SSO.
If select a link in a browser to a service provider and I haven't been set up on the IDp after I have my account created at the IDp and authenticated to the SP what is stored? is it my ipddress? if I tried to connect to the same SP from a different machine would I need to be registered on the IDp again. 
Or is it done another way?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

An IdP creates a SAML assertion about an authenticated subject.

Based upon the NameID format  being used an opaque handle could be transmitted ("transient NameID format") or an email address ("email NameID format") or even some other id can be transmitted from the IdP to the SP. Furhtermore attribute statements could be used to transmit additional information about the subject.

Authentication happens on the IdP, however it's not defined in the SAMLv2 spec how this has to take place.

If authentication happened a "session" is established at the IdP. Most IdP implemenatations use a cookie to track the "session". So when you return to the IdP again there is no need for re-authentication unless an SP mandates this. ("ForceAuth" in the SAML AuthnRequest).

This is only a quick overview, reading the SAMLv2 tech overview (https://wiki.oasis-open.org/security/Saml2TechOverview) certainly gives you more insights.